# Какие существуют слайдеры с динамическим добавлением элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо реализовать слайдер carousel для динамического списка, в котором элементы добавляются/удаляются и их количество и ширина всегда разная.

Пожалуйста, приведите пример реализации.

**UPD** принцип работы слайдера как в примере "Add & Remove" - **ссылка в ответе**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Нашла такой ресурс](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), может кому пригодится.

Принцип работы как в слайдере "Add & Remove"

```
 $('.add-remove').slick({
 slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
 });
 $('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
 slideIndex++;
$('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3>' + slideIndex + '</h3></div>');
 });

 $('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
 $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);
 if (slideIndex !== 0){
 slideIndex--;
 }
});
```

Comment: весь фреймворк выложить?

Comment: Нет, добавить прямо в ответ рабочий пример с использованием этого слайдера, демонстрирующий нужное вам поведение

Comment: А еще можете пояснить, зачем вы упоминали связь с бутстрапом? Просто из вашего ответа непонятно, почему этот слайдер подходит под ваши требования

Comment: потому что проект на бутстрапе. хотя может это и не имеет значения

Comment: мой вопрос был не в рабочем примере, а в ссылке на готовое решение

Comment: Судя по подошедшему примеру, использование bootstrap не имеет никакого значения и это лишняя информация в вопросе.

Comment: вопрос уже отредактирован, какие еще тут "требуются правки"?

Comment: @VenZell: сделано)